# Fill multiple connected dropdowns with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropdown

I have two connected (chained) dropdowns in a asp.net web form.

```
<p>
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="country" ID="ddlCountry" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<p>
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="city" ID="ddlCity" ></asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<input type="button" class="magicBtn" value="Magic" />
```

And this is the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(".magicBtn").click(function () {

                var obj = { CountryId: "2", CityId: "3" };
                $(".country").val(obj.CountryId).trigger("change");
                $(".city").val(obj.CityId);
            });

        });
```

When I assign the values like that, only the country dropdown appears, then the city dropdown is populated, however, its value does not appear. If i click on the magicBtn again, then it appears.

I guess as as soon as i click on the button, change event(__doPstBack) is triggered so before assigning the city value, page is being refreshed, but options are retrieved, then by second click, options are ready so assigment is OK.
 
(*At this point, i am curious how the value is being assigned to city dropdown. I am surprised when I see it filled on second click as i supposed that whenever i click the magic button*, `trigger("change")` *do postback and city value assignment never happens. So I thought that after the first click, country option is selected, then the second click comes, checks the option value, if same then do not postback, so it can pass to the line below to assign city dropdown*, ***however*** *when i was inspecting this on dev tools, i saw that it did postback although the option value of the country was same. So despite postback, how city dropdown is assigned?* The gif is related with this issue.)

[image]

So what i want is, right after first click, **both the country and the city** option values are assigned to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **first** click, jquery trigger method triggers the postback, page's `load` event and then the dropdown's `selectedIndexChanged` event are fired. What selectedIndexChanged event has is

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlCity.Items.Clear();
            FillCityDropdown(ddlCity, Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value));
        }
```

So country dropdown is also populated, however after this `$(".city").val(obj.CityId);` assignment, so because this assignment was before the populating it was not working.

By **second** click, again the the change triggers a postback but now, because the selected index of country dropdown is not changed, its event is not fired, so nothing happens in codebehind, however on client side city dropdown was populated and assignment comes true.

#### Solution

I solve the problem like this

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(".magicBtn").click(function () {
                
                var obj = { CountryId: "2", CityId: "3" };
                $(".country").val(obj.CountryId);
                __doPostBack("ddlCountry", obj.CityId);
            });
            
        });
```

Index.aspx.cs

```
 string controlName = "";
 string controlArg = "";
 
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     controlName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
     controlArg = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");
    //..
 }


protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ddlCity.Items.Clear();
     FillCityDropdown(ddlCity,   Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value));
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlArg))
         ddlCity.SelectedValue = controlArg;
}
```